# Count same name items in mysql table php?

Tags: php, mysql

How can i count items qho had the same name in a mysql table with php , i tried this but he always print the only first one but i have 5items with the same Custumer name.. this my code..

```
<?php
include ('Connection.php');
$con= mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
 $Codigo=$_GET['nbCliente'];
 $sql = "
SELECT $Codigo
     , COUNT(*) 
  FROM pedidos 
 GROUP 
    BY nbCliente = '$Codigo'
";
 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
 $result = array();
array_push($result,array(
 "codigo"=>$res['Codigo'],
 "articulos"=>$res['articulos'],
 "precio"=>$res['precio'],
 "cantidad"=>$res['cantidad'],
"Nomb_Cliente"=>$res['nbCliente'],
"NombVende"=>$res['nbvendedor'],
 "image"=>$res['image_path']
)
);
 echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
 mysqli_close($con);
 }
```

Comment: `group by` groups by field, not by result of assigning.

Comment: Instead of `GROUP BY` in your query, have you tried `WHERE nbCliente = '$Codigo'` instead?

Comment: thank you @McRed for your help , i tried that too but still send me the first one..should i use a  for loop?

Comment: Can you paste what you tried?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: thank you @tadman the problem is i know nothing on php i just copy the code on the web ...i did know tha

Comment: Cutting and pasting random code from the web is like eating food you find in a dumpster: Risky at the best of times. Start with a guide like [PHP the Right Way](http://phptherightway.com) to keep you on the right path.

Comment: I'd also strongly advise you to look at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like 
[Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and much stronger guidance on how to write your code and organize your files.

Answer (score 0):

I think the query you are looking for should look like this:

```
select nbCliente, count(nbCliente) from pedidos where nbCliente = $Codigo group by nbCliente
```